# How can I add a big flash banner to the top of my Wordpress blog?

Tags: flash, wordpress, banner

I don't know if it is possible to add a Flash banner into a Wordpress theme... Ideally, this banner would be in the header of the site always. Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Adding unnecessary Flash to your site is a sure way to annoy your users.

Comment: Could you please let me know the address of the blog where you plan to do this so I can add it to my "This way there be dragons" list?

Comment: The question is difficult to answer in it's current form. If you are having problems editing a particular template, consider posting the relevant snippets from it, how you expect it to work, and how it is not working. If you're asking as a WordPress user rather than a theme developer, I'd suggest using http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very much possible. What I would recommend is to use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to replace the your current header with a Flash movie. This way it will degrade gracefully for everyone that lacks a proper flash player, and also you get the benefit of proper google indexing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the corresponding .php file that contains your banner (I don't know what version of WordPress you're using).

The code will be resource-intensive and ugly, though.

Comment: "resource-intensive and ugly" - that's a pretty broad statement!

Comment: Thank you for expressing your opinion with a downvote. And I was talking about the code, not Flash.